# Hi, i have installed JDK 16.0.1 version and in eclipse i have created a maven project and i want to add cucumber dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, cucumber, pom.xml

have installed JDK 16.0.1 version and in eclipse  have created a maven project and want to add cucumber dependencies, please help.  have tried to copy the build and properties from others but version of java is different but changed to 16.0.1 but still  not seeing the cucumber dependencies added

Answer (score 0):

I wasn’t aware that maven ran with jdk 16.0.1.   What version of maven are you running?